# Prestashop "file not found issue"

Tags: file, prestashop, attachment

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for the help.

I have a problem with the attached documents on a prestashop 1.6.1.11 on VPS ubuntu.

In fact, whether it's the old files (which worked until recently) or the new ones I add, when you want to open or download one of these pdf's I get an empty page with just "file not found".

However, in the database if I go to search them with the SQL command of the BO :

`` SELECT b.*, a.* , IFNULL(virtual_product_attachment.products, 0) as products FROM `q55vl_attachment` a LEFT JOIN `q55vl_attachment_lang` b ON (b.`id_attachment` = a.`id_attachment` AND b.`id_lang` = 1) LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_attachment, COUNT(*) as products FROM q55vl_product_attachment GROUP BY id_attachment) AS virtual_product_attachment ON a.id_attachment = virtual_product_attachment.id_attachment WHERE 1 ORDER BY a.`id_attachment` ASC LIMIT 0, 50 ``

I found them all. And when I download a file it has pdf-1.4 in the header of the file (as source).

I read a topic that it would be a migration problem and that it was enough to reimport the download file in binaries, it's done but it didn't change anything. And that doesn't explain why the new files don't pass either.

I tried to put everything in 777 access to check if it's a problem of access to resources, nothing either.

I'm with the variable dev mode enabled, no errors come out. On Apache, the vhost and prestashop no error either.

As a result, I'm completely stuck and I wonder if anyone has ever dealt with this problem and managed to solve it?

Thanks a lot

PS : I asked on the prestashop forum but no answer for a month with ups, so I try here !

Comment: Is this nginx webserver ? You might need adding proper nginx rules to allow PDF download - See https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/nginx/

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed it was a hybrid with apache and nginx. I switched all on apache with the correct extension and it works.
thanks again !